# Cancelar AsyncTask y el ProgressDialog al pulsar boton atras en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-asynctask

Tengo un `AsyncTask` que lanza un `ProgressDialog` en forma modal, que no se pueda cancelar.

En el `onPreExecute` inicio el `progressDialog`

```
progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "titulo","progreso x", true);
```

y el  `asyncTask` lo inicio con:

```
new initMap().execute();
```

Lo que intento hacer que durante la carga, si se pulsa el botón atrás, pare la tarea del `asyncTask` , cierre el dialog y salga de la `activity`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dentro de la clase `MainActivity` crea los atributos:

```
private Task task;
private ProgressDialog progress;
```

Crea una subclase dentro de `MainActivity` que herede de `AsyncTask`, por ejemplo:

```
private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
@Override protected void onPostExecute() {
 progress.dismiss();
}

@Override protected void onPreExecute() {
 progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "titulo","progreso x", true);
}

@Override protected void doInBackground() {
    for(int i = 0; i<60; i++){
        if(!isCancelled()) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            } else break;
    }
}

}
```

Ejecuta la `asyncTask` así:

```
task = (Task) new Task().execute();
```

Luego reimplementa el metodo `onKeyDown` en la `MainActivity` y agrega el código para cancelar la `asynctask` cuando se presiona atrás:

```
@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
       if(task != null && task.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
          task.cancel(true);
          progress.dismiss();
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Veo que los progress dialog se puede poner:             progress.setCancelable(true);
            progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); así se estalvia lo de tener que detectar el botón físico, ya que por defecto se cierra con el botón atrás virtual y físico.

Comment: El task.cancel(true); me funciona al revés es decir para cancelar cancel(false)

Answer (score 1):

En este caso detecta el evento "back" y cancela el AsyncTask y Dialog:

```
@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
       if(initMap!= null && task.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){

          //Cancela el AsynckTast.
          initMap.cancel(true);
          //Cancela el ProgressDialog.
          progress.dismiss();

          //Puedes usar finish() si te encuentras dentro de la Activity.
          //finish();


        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Usando el método [cancel(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)) asegura que el Asynctask sea terminado aúnque no se haya completado la tarea, de otra forma puedes usar [cancel(false)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean))

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a la publicación del compañero @Michel_Escalante_Alvarez he adaptado su código a lo que he ido encontrado por SO.

**Creando ProgressDialog cancelable`**

Para crear un `ProgressDialog` que sea cancelable con la pulsación del botón físico/virtual atrás, pero evitando que si se pulsa fuera del dialogo no se cierre.

```
progress.setCancelable(true);
progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

y al cancelar el dialogo se intercepta con

```
progress.setOnCancelListener(...)
```

Para cancelar el `asyncTask`

```
cancel(false);
```

Código entero de la creación del dialogo:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    //Show dialog bar
    progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progress.setTitle("titulo");
    progress.setMessage("progreso x");
    progress.setCancelable(true);
    progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progress.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            cancel(false); //se cancela el asyntask
        }
    });
    progress.show();
}
```

**Controlador al cancelar la tarea**

En el evento `doInBackground` con la función `isCancelled` se puede obtener si se necesita cancelar.

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    if (!isCancelled()) {
     //seguir la tarea
    } return false;
    return true;
 }
```

**Finalizar completamente la tarea**

Al terminar la tarea correctamente o bien se a cancelado se computa al evento  `onPostExecute`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (result) {
        progress.dismiss();
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute: Finalizado correctamente" );
    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "onPostExecute: Cancelación por parte del usuario");
    }
}
```

**Capturar la cancelación**

Se puede interceptar el evento antes de cancelar con `onCancelled`

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled(Boolean aBoolean) {
    super.onCancelled(aBoolean);
    Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled: " + aBoolean );
}
```